# MSSQL 2008: Get last updated record by specific field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having this simplified table called `Content` in MSSQL:

```
ContentID     UpdatedAt               FileID
1             2014-01-01 00:00:00     File-A
1             2014-02-02 00:00:00     File-B
1             2014-03-03 00:00:00     File-B
2             2012-12-30 00:00:00     File-X
2             2012-12-31 00:00:00     File-Y
```

---

What I want to achieve is following:

Get each row from the table `Content`, where `FileID` has been updated compared to it's previous version. The result should be as following:

```
ContentID     UpdatedAt               FileID
1             2014-02-02 00:00:00     File-B
2             2012-12-31 00:00:00     File-Y
```

---

What I have tried so far:

- Looked up for different solutions and found the LAG() function, which seemed promising. However this feature only seems to be available in MSSQL 2012, as the error "The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled" states.
- Tried to wrap my head around cursors, but since I'm a noob to this, I couldn't find a running solution.
- Lots of nested queries, ugh... Since a new row is created for each update, I assume nested queries are not the way to go because of performance-reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012, you would just use `lag()`.  You can replicate this in various ways in SQL Server 2008.  Here is a method using `cross apply`:

```
select c.*
from content c cross apply
     (select top 1 c2.*
      from content c2
      where c2.contentId = c.contentId and c2.UpdatedAt < c.UpdatedAt
      order by c2.UpdatedAt desc
     ) cprev
where c.FileId <> cprev.FileId;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that was exactly what I was looking for. Another new feature learned.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to make an update. Since the problem is a bit different, I made a new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404335/mssql-2008-get-last-updated-record-by-specific-field-part-2