# MSSQL 2008: Get last updated record by specific field (Part 2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Yesterday, I posted this question here: [MSSQL 2008: Get last updated record by specific field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382131/mssql-2008-get-last-updated-record-by-specific-field/26382251)

Gordon Linoff came up with a good solution and I was happy until today, when I realized I posted only half of the scenarios. Here's my new Question:

Given this table `Content`:

```
ContentId     lastUpdate              FileId    IrrelevantField
1             2014-01-01 00:00:00     File-A    Dr. Hoo     /* user uploads file*/
1             2014-01-02 00:00:00     File-B    Dr. Hoo     /* (!) user uploads new file */
1             2014-01-03 00:00:00     File-B    Dr. Who     /* user updates info */

2             2014-02-01 00:00:00     File-M    41          /* (!) user uploads file */
2             2014-02-02 00:00:00     File-M    42          /* user updates info */

3             2014-03-01 00:00:00     File-S    Donald Duck /* user uploads file*/
```

---

Basically what I want is to get all rows that meet these conditions:

- They have a different `FileId` than it's previous row with the same `ContentId`.
- If the `FileId` has never changed, get the first ever submitted row (this applies in the example to `ContentId` = 2 & 3.)

`IrrelevantField` triggers a row update. My goal is, to get the rows, when `FileId` has changed.

---

The output would be following:

```
ContentId     lastUpdate              FileId    IrrelevantField
1             2014-01-02 00:00:00     File-B    Dr. Hoo
2             2014-02-01 00:00:00     File-M    41
3             2014-03-01 00:00:00     File-S    Donald Duck
```

---

`FileId` is never `NULL`.

---

I have tried to add a `OUTER APPLY` to Gordon Linoff's solution, so I can check, whether the `FileId`  is still the same as in the initial upload. But that has gotten me irrelevant Updates as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this should work with all your scenario..

```
;with cte
as
(
select rank() over(partition by fileid,contentid order by lastupdate ) id, ContentId,lastUpdate,FileId,IrrelevantField from tablename
)
select ContentId,lastUpdate,FileId,IrrelevantField from(
select row_number() over(partition by contentid order by lastupdate desc) fstid, * from cte where id=1) a where fstid=1
```

Comment: Not sure if it is a problem, but something to be aware of, this will give the wrong result if you ever change a fileID back to something it has already been, e.g. if Content 1 was changed to `File-A` on `2014-01-04`, this would still show `File-B` as the latest change. [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fc0a/1).

Answer (score 2):

You were along the right lines changing it to an outer apply, then you can change the `WHERE` clause slightly to allow for records where there is no previous record.

```
SELECT  c.ContentID,
        c.LastUpdate,
        c.FileID,
        c.IrrelevantField,
        FileID2 = c2.FileID
FROM    Content AS c 
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 c2.FileID
            FROM    Content AS c2
            WHERE   c2.ContentID = c.ContentID
            AND     c2.LastUpdate < c.LastUpdate
            ORDER BY c2.LastUpdate DESC
        ) AS c2
WHERE   c.FileId != c2.FileId
OR      c2.FileID IS NULL;
```

This means though that two records are returned for ContentID = 1 (and any other content with changes):

```
ContentID   LastUpdate  FileID  IrrelevantField FileID2
1           2014-01-01  File-A  Dr. Hoo         NULL
1           2014-01-02  File-B  Dr. Hoo         File-A
2           2014-02-01  File-M  41              NULL
3           2014-03-01  File-S  Donald Duck     NULL
```

So you will need to use a further ranking function to limit this to only the latest record:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  c.ContentID,
            c.LastUpdate,
            c.FileID,
            c.IrrelevantField,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.ContentID ORDER BY c.LastUpdate DESC)
    FROM    Content AS c 
            OUTER APPLY
            (   SELECT  TOP 1 c2.FileID
                FROM    Content AS c2
                WHERE   c2.ContentID = c.ContentID
                AND     c2.LastUpdate < c.LastUpdate
                ORDER BY c2.LastUpdate DESC
            ) AS c2
    WHERE   c.FileId != c2.FileId
    OR      c2.FileID IS NULL
)
SELECT  c.ContentID,
        c.LastUpdate,
        c.FileID,
        c.IrrelevantField
FROM    CTE AS c
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The query below uses `lead` to create a derived table containing all rows where FileId has changed plus the 1st row. It then uses `row_number()` to display either the 1st row if there are no changed FileIds for that ContentId (`rn_asc = 1 and rn_desc = 1`) or all other rows where FileId has changed (`rn_asc > 1`). If you just want the 1st row where FileId changed, use `rn_asc = 2` instead of `rn_asc > 1`.

```
select * from (
    select * ,
    row_number() over (partition by ContentId order by lastUpdate asc) rn_asc,
    row_number() over (partition by ContentId order by lastUpdate desc) rn_desc
    from (
        select * 
        from (
            select * , 
            lead(FileId) over (partition by ContentId order by lastUpdate) previousFileId
            from content c
        ) t1 where previousFileId <> FileId or previousFileId IS NULL
    ) t2 
) t3 where (rn_asc = 1 and rn_desc = 1) or rn_asc > 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on MSSQL 2008 where lead() and lag() are not available. But thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

```
select ContentId, lastUpdate, FileId, IrrelevantField
from (  
    select  row_number() over(partition by contentid order by lastupdate desc) LastChgsl, *
    from   
    (  
        select  
        row_number() over(partition by fileid order by lastupdate) FileChgSl, *   
        from tablename  
    )V where FileChgSl = 1
)V1 where LastChgsl = 1
```